# Integer value inside name of object (xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, integer, objectname

My idea is to add generated integer value to the name of UIImageView. Here is an example: I have three UIImageViews named imageView1, imageView2, imageView3. When a button is pressed I have there this simple code:
`self.value = value + 1;`
(and of course I have this "value" declared) Now I want add some code which says something like:
`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[imageView(value) setImage:img];`
So this I want this part of code `...[imageView(value)...` to use the value I defined above. How could I do this?

Comment: Um, use an array of UIImageViews perhaps ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `tag` for your image views:

```
// set tag
[imageView1 setTag:1];
[imageView2 setTag:2];
//...

// get the image view with the tag
[(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:value] setImage:img];
//...
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happen...no error but also no image shows.

here is my code:
`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:value] setImage:img];`

Comment: And in view did load I put `[imageView1 setTag:1];
[imageView2 setTag:2];`

Comment: @TomasJ what's the value of `cislotatku`? It must be 1~3 if you set tags: 1, 2, 3 (only numeric is allowed).

Comment: It's allways previous value + 1. In viewdidload it's declared as 0 so when button is first pressed it's 0+1 then again 1+1 etc

Comment: @TomasJ please put a NSLog for your value & image in button pressed method, check whether it is right or not.

Comment: I did. It is right (both value and image) I can't find out where is the problem.

Comment: @TomasJ that's weird.. Have you added your image views to your self.view as subviews?? I think it's an another issue in your code then.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How do you mean as subviews?

Comment: I'm sorry my bad It's OK now I put these imageviews in wrong place.

Comment: @TomasJ __subviews__: [self.view addSubview:imageView1]; :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tag, or you can put the `UIImageViews` into an `NSArray`. Then you can do something like

```
[((UIImageView *)[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:self.value]) setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried to did according to your requirement.

my ViewController Class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
[super viewDidLoad];
ExtendedUIImageView *eimage=[[ExtendedUIImageView alloc]initExtendedUIImageViewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac.png"];
UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac.png"];
[eimage addUIImage:img1 ToExtendedImageViewWithRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100) withTag:1];
[eimage addUIImage:img2 ToExtendedImageViewWithRect:CGRectMake(210, 100, 100, 100) withTag:2];
[eimage addUIImage:img3 ToExtendedImageViewWithRect:CGRectMake(320, 100, 100, 100) withTag:3];
[self.view addSubview:eimage];


}

- (IBAction)chageImage:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"#####");
     UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
    [eimage replaceImage:img2 forTag:3];
}
```

I Extended the UIView Class and created new Class ExtendedImageView class

ExtendedImageView.h

```
@interface ExtendedUIImageView : UIView
-(id)initExtendedUIImageViewWithFrame:(CGRect)rect;
-(void)addUIImage:(UIImage *)img ToExtendedImageViewWithRect:(CGRect)rect withTag:(int)n;
-(void)replaceImage:(UIImage *)newImg forTag:(int)n;    
@end
```

ExtendedImageView.m

```
@implementation ExtendedUIImageView
-(id)initExtendedUIImageViewWithFrame:(CGRect)rect{
    if([super initWithFrame:rect]){
        return  self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)addUIImage:(UIImage *)img ToExtendedImageViewWithRect:(CGRect)rect withTag:(int)n{
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
    //[imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    imgView.frame=rect;
    [imgView setTag:n];
    [self addSubview:imgView];

}

-(void)replaceImage:(UIImage *)newImg forTag:(int)n{
    for(UIView * img in [self subviews]){
        if([img isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]&&[img tag]==n){
            ((UIImageView *)img).image=newImg;
        }
    }
}
@end
```